# Apache not redirecting without closing slash in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Below is my htaccess file I use for bootstrap page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

When I write URL in my browser like:
"www.mydomain.com/mypage"
it redirects to main VPS account domain but when I do: "www.mydomain.com/mypage/" it works as it should (closing slash suddenly makes a difference). Could someone point me to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was not an error related to htaccess. What caused this was "UseCanonicalName" apache configuration setting that was set to On.
Changing this and restarting Apache fixed the problem.